# glReadPixels and alpha channels returning 1.0

Tags: opengl, sdl

I'm reading pixel data from a framebuffer, and everything seems to work, except for the alpha value, which is always 1.0

```
  GLfloat lebuf[areasize * 4];
  glReadPixels(xstart, ystart, partw, parth, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, lebuf);
```

I've set the window creation code to support an alpha channel:

```
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
```

Is there any other place I should look at for checking why the alpha channel seems to be 1.0 all the time? Better yet, is there another way (other than glReadPixels) to get the texture into client memory, from the framebuffer?

**edit**: this is how I clear the buffer:

```
 glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Did you try to glReadPixels with another format, such GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, instead of GL_FLOAT ? Just in case it is a driver bug ?

Comment: Did you try to remove all the rendering and keep only the glClear and glReadPixels ? Is the behaviour the same in this case ?

Comment: Yeah, I removed the drawings and only tried the glCLear thing, it's still a black, non transparent picture. I'll try with GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE soon

Comment: Oh wow.. enabling GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE worked.. it's not got transparent backgrounds! Puzzling!

Comment: Have you checked OpenGL errors, btw?

Comment: When I ran them previously with GL_FLOAT on, there wasn't any error that I remember.. which was pretty strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you check:

- That you SDL has accepted your format (`glGetIntegerv(GL_ALPHA_BITS, bits)`)?
- That your color clear is not 1 (`glClearColor`). What if you clear to 0.5 and retrieve the buffer before rendering. Do you retrieve 0.5?
- That you alpha buffer is not write locked (`glColorMask(GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE,GL_TRUE)`)?
- That you correctly clear your alpha buffer at the end of each frame?
- That your blend function will write the correct alpha value to the buffer?

Comment: After checking with gDEBugger, GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE is 0,0,0,0, GL_ALPHA_BITS is 8, and GL_COLOR_WRITEMASK is n/a, but I did glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE)..

Comment: Try to clear with `glClearColor(0,0,0,0.5)` and check that you retrieve 0.5 from the frame buffer.

Comment: GL_BLEND_DST_ALPHA is zero though, but so is GL_BLEND_DST_RGB and GL_BLEND_DST

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GLUT, remember you have to set your main window as follows:

`glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);`

otherwise glReadPixels will read always alpha channel = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following line.. problem will solved.

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
```